# Why do I see "&lt;" and "&gt;" in Unity C# code?

Tags: unity, c#

I copied Unity code from a website and now it contains stuff like `&amp;lt; T &amp;gt;` which my IDE flags as an error.

It looks like the intended text has been corrupted somehow. What is this supposed to be, and how can I correct it?

```
public class Tree&lt;T&gt;
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable&lt;Tree&lt;T&gt;&gt; Childs { get; set; }
    public bool Opened { get; set; }

    public Tree()
    {
        Childs = Enumerable.Empty&lt;Tree&lt;T&gt;&gt;();
        Opened = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the symbols `<` & `>` (also known as the 'less than symbol' and the 'greater than symbol')?

Comment: @Pikalek Yes this for example Tree&lt;T&gt; So the &lt;T&gt and at this line Tree&lt;T&gt;&gt They are all presenting < > ? Then how should the line Tree&lt;T&gt;&gt be ?

Comment: `&lt;` means `<` and `&gt;` means `>`. Simply replace them with the corresponding signs.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi Are you following code from an online tutorial?

Comment: @Pikalek Not a tutorial but a code of someone else from a website and the code have this symbols ( Solved and fixed them all Thank you )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML code uses angle brackets < and > to denote tags in its markup structure, eg.

> <p>This is a paragraph of text in HTML markup, and some of it is <em>*emphasized*</em>.</p>

Because of this, < > characters appearing in the text of the document can confuse the parsing. To avoid this, we can use what's called an escape sequence to describe the bracket character we want to use, instead of writing the character itself. In HTML, the escape sequences for these characters are:

- < = `&lt;` "less than"
- > = `&gt;` "greater than"

(Tip: hit the edit button to see where I've had to use escape sequences to ensure this answer renders as I intended!)

Many tools for editing web pages will automatically search text for < > characters and replace them with the matching escape sequences for you, so the author doesn't need to fuss with this.

Sometimes, they're over-eager about this, and convert characters that didn't need to be converted, resulting in mangled code samples like you showed in the question.

Fortunately, we can simply Find & Replace these two escape sequences back to the intended bracket characters to get the code as it was written (I also fixed the pluralization of "child" while I was at it):

```
public class Tree<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Tree<T>> Children { get; set; }
    public bool Opened { get; set; }

    public Tree()
    {
        Children = Enumerable.Empty<Tree<T>>();
        Opened = true;
    }
}
```

In C#, angle brackets like these are used to denote [Generics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/), special types that can adapt to one or more given type parameters.

For example, the generic `List<T>` means "A list that can contain some type `T`." By providing a concrete type like `int` we can form `List<int>`, a list of integers. And we can even nest those types, to make stuff like `List<List<int>>`, a list of lists of integers. That's what's going on where you see `IEnumerable<Tree<T>>` — it's an enumerable collection of Tree nodes containing Data of some type `T` ("enumerable" meaning we can iterate over the members of the collection in some order)